# Find $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x \ln \left( 1 + \frac{\ln x}{x} \right)}{\ln x}$

Tags: limits, logarithms

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x \ln \left( 1 + \frac{\ln x}{x} \right)}{\ln x}$$
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{\ln x}{x} = 0$$
Then the given Question look like this 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x \ln 1}{\ln x} = 0$$

But the answer is 1 .. why this is so..

Comment: because the question doesn't look like that

Comment: the answer is 1 by simple taylor expansion, or just something like $x-10x^2 \le \ln(1+x) \le x+10x^2$ for small $x>0$.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh [Do not use \dfrac or other displaystyle in title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You noted correctly:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{\ln x}{x} = 0,$$
but:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x \ln \left( 1 + \frac{\ln x}{x} \right)}{\ln x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{\ln x}\cdot \ln \left( 1 + \frac{\ln x}{x} \right)\ne \underbrace{\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{\ln x}}_{=\infty}\cdot\underbrace{\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\ln \left( 1 + \frac{\ln x}{x} \right)}_{=0},$$
because the first limit on the right does not exist. See [Limit properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Properties).

Alternatively:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x \ln \left( 1 + \frac{\ln x}{x} \right)}{\ln x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \ln \left( 1 + \frac{\ln x}{x} \right)^{\frac{x }{\ln x}}=\ln \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{\ln x}{x} \right)^{\frac{x }{\ln x}}=\ln e=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $y = \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1/x}{1} = 0  \ ( \text{L'Hopital's rule }) $$

So, as $x\to \infty, y\to 0$

Now, $$l = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x\ln(1+\frac{\ln x}{x})}{\ln x} = \lim_{y\to0}\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y} = 1$$

Answer (score 2):

In general,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x,g(x))\neq\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x,\lim_{y\to\infty}g(y))
$$
which is why you can't just replace $\frac{\ln x}{x}$ with $0$ into the numerator $x\ln(1+\frac{\ln x}{x})$.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, so please don't downvote.  Nevertheless, here's a plot:

[image]